# Code optimization, adaptation to a large number of conditions

Tags: magento2, php, optimization, if, singleton

I need to make a condition, if the server code has a certain value, then it will set the appropriate currency.
I did this via an `if else` condition. But if there are many 5+ conditions, it will look wrong. Help optimise and shorten the code by using an array

```
        $de = 'de';
        $currencyEuro = 'EUR';

        $uk = 'uk';
        $currencyPound = 'GBP';

        if ($this->getStoreCurrency() !== $currencyEuro && $_SERVER['HTTP_LANGUAGE'] == $de) {
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyEuro);
        } elseif ($this->getStoreCurrency() !== $currencyPound && $_SERVER['HTTP_LANGUAGE'] == $uk) {
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currencyPound);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you can use this code for simplicity

```
    $array = [
        'de' => 'EUR',
        'uk' => 'GBP'
    ];
    $currency = $this->getStoreCurrency();

    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
        if ($currency!== $value && $_SERVER['HTTP_LANGUAGE'] == $k) {
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($value);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and if I need to use several languages for the euro, do I need to duplicate or can this be simplified?
'de' => 'EUR', 'fr' => 'EUR', ...

Comment: yes. you can use it as you've mentioned.